# Como retornar um arquivo para o cliente?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso retornar um arquivo na minha ação para que o cliente possa baixá-lo. No meu código atual, o arquivo está sendo salvo no **servidor**.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ExibirPrintRPA(int? id)
{
    string _nameFile = string.Empty;
    EmissaoPrintRPA lemissao = new EmissaoPrintRPA();
    EmissaoPrintRPA emissaoPrints = _EmissaoPrintRPAApplicationService.GetById(lemissao);           
    var _imagem = emissaoPrints.ST_IMAGEM;
    _imagem = _imagem.Replace(" ", "+");
    int mod4 = _imagem.Length % 4;
    if (mod4 > 0)
    {
        _imagem += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
    }

    var _img = Convert.FromBase64String(_imagem);
    var _filePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.{2}", 
        Server.MapPath("~/Files/Downloads"), _nameFile, "jpeg");
    using (var fs = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(_img, 0, _img.Length);                
        fs.Flush();               
    }

    return Json(new 
    { 
        file = string.Format("{0}.{1}", _nameFile, "jpeg"), 
        path = _filePath 
    });
}
```

Comment: Quem define onde o arquivo é salvo é o cliente, você não consegue controlar isso pelo servidor.

Comment: @LINQ, sim entendo porém do jeito que tá o código postado o arquivo está sendo salvo na pasta do projeto, lá no Servidor e não salva na maquina do usuário.

Comment: Ah, nossa, não foi isso que deu a entender ao ler a pergunta. Você está usando ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Não, estou usando o ASP.net MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de tentar **salvar** um arquivo, você precisa retornar o tal arquivo para o chamador da sua ação.

Isso pode ser feito usando o método [`File()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Eu não entendi bem essa manipulação que você fez antes de `Convert.FromBase64String`, mas estou assumindo que ela esteja certa.

Como o método `Convert.FromBase64String` já retorna um *array* de *bytes*, você pode simplesmente passá-lo para o método `File`.

Note que você precisa informar como segundo parâmetro o *content type* do arquivo e, como terceiro parâmetro, o nome do mesmo.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExibirPrintRPA(int? id)
{
    string _nameFile = string.Empty;

    EmissaoPrintRPA lemissao = new EmissaoPrintRPA();
    EmissaoPrintRPA emissaoPrints = _EmissaoPrintRPAApplicationService.GetById(lemissao);           

    var _imagem = emissaoPrints.ST_IMAGEM;
    _imagem = _imagem.Replace(" ", "+");

    int mod4 = _imagem.Length % 4;

    if (mod4 > 0)
    {
        _imagem += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
    }

    var bytesImagem = Convert.FromBase64String(_imagem);

    return File(bytesImagem, "ContentTypeArquivo", "NomeArquivo");
}
```

Comment: está dando erro na ultima linha: `return File(`, pois no meu caso estou usando um `JsonResult` e não um `ActionResult`,

Comment: Você vai ter que mudar o tipo de retorno ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Você quer retornar um arquivo e não um JSON, portanto o retorno vai ser do tipo `FileContentResult` (`ActionResult` funciona porque é o tipo mais abstrato).